# How can I query models in Django with attributes in a JSONField?

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a JSONField. The JSON field contains a title that I'd like to use to identify the object. Obviously, I can just use a loop, checking if each object contains the title I'm looking for. But I was wondering if there was a more pythonic way to do it. Something like this:

```
myObj = MyModel.objects.get(myjson__title='Title')
```

The above code doesn't work, obviously. But is there an approach that can be taken without using a loop?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I did give you an upvote because I think you were on the right track, but it didn't work when I tried it so I can't accept it because it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming `title` is the `key` in the `JSONField`

```
myObj = MyModel.objects.get(myjson__contains={'title':'Title'})
```